# Get value from URL variable. PHP. The form uses POST method

Tags: php, post, get

I would like to save the text from a textbox.
I want to get the value of idForo in the URL.

```
http://localhost/foro1/indice.php?idForo=1
```

I get the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: idForo in C:\xampp\htdocs\foro1\indice.php on line 44
```

**The controller**

```
if (isset($_GET['newAnswer'])){
    $idForo=$_POST['idForo']; /*line 44*/
    $newAnswer=$_POST['newAnswer'];
    //Save new answer using PDO
    header("Location:indice.php?idForo=$idForo");
```

}

**The form**

```
<form method='post' action='indice.php'>
            <textarea rows='7' cols='60' name='newAnswer' required></textarea> <br>
            <input type='submit' class='responder' value='Responder' name='comentario'>
</form>
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: I cannot see idForo within the form. If it is not there, it will not be sent.

Answer (score 2):

To get variables from the query string, you need to use `$_GET`. `$_POST` represents data that is sent to the script via the HTTP POST method.

You're also translating (?) the post variable name for the textarea for some reason?

Try:

```
if (isset($_POST['nuevaRespuesta'], $_GET['idForo'])) {
    $idForo = $_GET['idForo']; /*line 44*/
    $newAnswer = $_POST['nuevaRespuesta'];
    //Save new answer using PDO
    header("Location: indice.php?idForo=$idForo");
}
```

Comment: To add up to that answer : what people also tends to do in this case, is to have a copy of the `$_GET` variable in a hidden input in the form. Like this : `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['idForo'] ?>" name="idForo" />`. Now the way you do it stays up to you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a variable, you need to use `$_GET`

in your example, you just need to do this:

```
$idForo = $_GET['idForo'];
```

this will create a new variable `$idForo` from the variable in your URL.  Hope this helps.

To get the variable into your form, you would need to change the first line to this:

```
<form method='post' action='indice.php?idForo=<?php $idForo ?>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

idForo might not be in the $POST array, so use the following to allow for that scenario:

```
  if(isset($_GET['idForo'])) {
    $idForo = $_GET['idForo'];
  } else {
    $idForo = null;
  }
```